# How do I make the sections un-numbered?

Tags: sectioning

Every time I call `\section{**Section Name**}`, a number appears to the left of the name of the section.

How do I hide this number?

Comment: Use `\section*{My section}`

Comment: Or `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`.

Comment: This is a very reasonable, but pretty elementary question. I recommend studying [The Not so short guide to LaTeX](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lshort-english/lshort.pdf); in particular, pg 41 describes `section*` :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use

```
\section*{My section}
```

to get un-numbered sections. For details refer to [The Not So Short Guide to LaTeX.](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lshort-english/lshort.pdf) (Page 41 describes `\section*`) (Thanks to @cmhughes for the link)

As per Heiko's suggestion, you can also use

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section*{My section}
\lipsum[1]
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

In the KOMA-Script classes there’s an additional possibility with (among others) `\addsec`. Quote `scrguien.pdf` (English documentation):

> In addition to the commands of the standard classes, KOMA-Script oﬀers the new commands `\addsec` and `\addchap`. They are similar to the standard commands `\chapter` and `\section`, except that they are unnumbered. They thus produce both a running heading and an entry in the table of contents.

Comment: hm. But setting `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` doesn't allow for `\ref` to work :-( But I do want to refer the sections by numbers, because the PDF structure still gives you that information. So I somehow need a way to just hide the number but without breaking `\ref`.