# Remove un-numbered section names

Tags: sectioning, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make the sections un-numbered?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72801/how-do-i-make-the-sections-un-numbered)

I'm using `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`.

All my section titles get numbered. How can I make them un-numbered?

Comment: To disable numbering document-wide, use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{<x>}`, where `<x>` is `-1` for disabling numbering of `part` and lower levels, `0` for `section` and lower levels, and so on …

Comment: To supplement @Qrrbrbirlbel's comment/answer, to produce an individual section that is not numbered use `\section*` instead of `\section`.

Comment: Correction: `0` is for `chapter` (that doesn't exist in `article`) and `1` is for section.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the starred versions of the sectioning commands :

```
\section*{My section}
\subsection*{My subsection}
\subsubsection*{My subsubsection}
...
```